# React + Add cache-busting to CSS and Js for third party url's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, caching

I am using react application.. The third party css and js files currently loaded into index.html, But my problem is when any changes updated in thrid party css/js files it;s not reflecting..

So I need to add cache busing to css and js files..

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="https://abcd.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://efgh.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://abcd.js?v=1"></script>
    <script src="https://efgh.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body class="test">
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Shall I remove the version(**?v=1**) ?

Or Shall i load all css/js files via js, there adding version based on time?

I am not sure which is the best method. Can you please suggest me..

App.js (sample)

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
    return (
      <div className="react-app">
        content.....
      </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm confused, if they are 3rd party components, why are you versioning them?

Comment: @James So shall I add like this <script src="https://efgh.js"></script> ?